# R dataframe: Multiple repeated measured variables of different time lengths

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, data-preprocessing

Not sure if this is the best place for this type of question, but I'll just try!

I have a semi-large dataset with multiple measures from one study I ran.
Some of them are repeated measures over different time points. This means, I have for example measured reaction time (RT) at three time points, but I have also measured amount of errors made for another task over two time points.
My idea was to make one large dataframe in R with all my measures in them, so I do not have to switch between dataframes in my data analyses. Sometimes I want to do some statistics on the data from the two different task(e.g. relate increase in RT of one task to amount of errors made (over time) of the other task). 
My reasoning was that this would become difficult if I had separate files with separate dataframes.

Now the problem, to do a repeated measures analysis in R, the repeated measures should be in LONG format. I now have everything in wide format (coming from SPSS). Does it however make sense to try and reshape my data, in such a manner that all my repeated measures (3 on RT and 2 on errors) are in long format? I cannot even imagine how that dataframe would look like, so unbalanced? 
Therefore, my question now is not necessarily how to do this, but if it makes sense at all?

Is it generally advisable to work with multiple dataframes and just take values between them in your statistical analyses?

I hope I make sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate shape for your dataframe depends on the analyses & function you will be using.  Almost all linear models analyses functions accept a single dataframe, so if you need any analyses of both, you probably should make a single, fully-long dataframe with one record for each observation.  Something like:

Subject Time Measure Value Cov1 Cov2 ...

where Measure is either "RT" or "Errors"

This will work for testing within-subject changes over time in RT vs changes over time in your 2nd measure "Errors" as a Measure:Time interaction.
Tests of just RT can be handled via either a subset=Measure=='RT' parameter or explicit dataset subsetting data=dsn[dsn$Measure=='RT',]